# Storage spaces direct only using 32gb for each cache device, is this normal?

Tags: windows, cache, storage-spaces-direct

I have two cache devices and 4 storage devices in two machines that are being mirrored. I ran some powershell to disable clustered storage (s2d) and in disk management I'm left with disks that are still partitioned to s2d. As you can see from my screenshot the cache disks (119.24GB SSD and 111.80GB SSD) have only 32GB of cache partitioned. Was it useless to buy bigger SSDs?

Screenshot at the following link (click on image to see full version)

[image: Storage Spaces Direct 32GB Cache]

Answer (score 1):

Try running `Get-StorageBusCache`. It is normal for the Storage Bus Layer Cache to use 32 GiB for pool and VD metadata and you should see

`CacheMetadataReserveBytes: 34359738368`

What you see in the Disk Management MMC doesn't fully show what Storage Spaces is doing with the disk. It probably has no idea what the cache is.

It's discussed as an option when not running in a cluster: *[Enable storage bus cache with Storage Spaces on standalone servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/storage-spaces-storage-bus-cache)*.